# Confiteor unum baptisma: cur utitur forma plurali?

Tags: plural, catechism-catholic-church

In [Symbolo Nicaeno](https://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Symbola/Nicaenum.html) dicitur:

> Confiteor unum baptisma in remissionem peccatorum.

Etiam in [Catechismo](https://www.vatican.va/archive/catechism_lt/p123a10_lt.htm#I.%20Unum%20Baptisma%20in%20remissionem%20peccatorum) reperitur nomen huic sacramento in forma plurali. Attamen nescio quid sit causa. Solebam enim putare vocabulum istud esse plurale tantum (sicut *nugae, -arum*) sed modo didici formam singularem exstare (in eodem ligamine reperiri potest forma *Baptismus*).

Comment: Quaestio bona est—melior monstrans quod verbum plurale esset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jam ideō quod ***ūnum** baptisma* positum·st appāret numerum plūrālem nōn esse, sed singulārem generis neutrī. Quārē igitur in *-a* exit? Scīlicet quia vocābulum Graecum est ([βάπτισμα](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%B2%CE%AC%CF%80%CF%84%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%B1)), eijusdem dēclīnātiōnis atque *hoc problēma, thema : : huijus problēmatis, thematis, baptismatis,* unde *haec problēmata, themata, baptismata* plūrālia fīunt.

*Baptismus* autem ille ab aliō vocābulō Graecō venit quod est [βαπτισμός](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%B2%CE%B1%CF%80%CF%84%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%BC%CF%8C%CF%82).

Comment: Sic quoque opinio mea .